# Bootstrap tabs doesn't work with Django include option

Tags: python, html, django

I am working with bootstrap tabs in Django on page ps_tabs_capacity.html which extends the base.html . Inside ps_tabs_capacity.html there is tab I include another ps_capacity1.html which should display Charts.js charts with info from external database .

ps_tabs_capacity.html:

```
{% extends 'app_sins/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block main%}

<body style="background-color:RGB(244,246,249)" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
       
        <br>
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">GnGp</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
                 
           </div>
          <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
            <h3>Menu 1</h3>
            
            {% include 'app_sins/ps_capacity1.html' %}

          </div>
          <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
           
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

          </body>    

     {% endblock main%}
```

in views.py I use two function (there are others, but not important here) ,first one is:

```
def index(request):   
   
    cursor1=connections['default'].cursor()   
    cursor1.execute(attach)    
    r1=dictfetchall(cursor1)
    cursor2=connections['default'].cursor()    
    cursor2.execute(gngp_ntp)
    r2=dictfetchall(cursor2)
    
    return render(request,'app_sins/ps_capacity1.html', {"all_post" : r1,"jokso" : r2})
```

and second one is:

```
def ps_tabs_capacity(request):

    return render (request,'app_sins/ps_tabs_capacity.html', {} )
```

in url.py there are:

```
path('sins/ps_tabs', views.ps_tabs_capacity, name='ps_tabs1'),
path('sins/', views.index, name='index'),
```

If I use only ps_capacity1.html with extension of base.html, everything is OK( got info from database, it works OK) but in bootstrap taps when I call it, It only appears charts without data/lines on it. It looks like I need to trigger function index in order to appear under the taps..
My questions are:

- What is needed to triger ps_capacity1.html under bootstrap taps?
- Do I need here to pass some argument and how to the function index?
- How my url.py and views.py should look like?

I would highly appreciate, if someone could help me with solution here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having a view (Here `index`) render a template (Here `ps_capacity1.html`) does not mean that when the template is included in another the view will be magically called (A template can be rendered by multiple views...) If your template needs some data it needs to be passed into the context of the template which is including it, i.e. you need to pass `all_post` and `jokso` in the context for the view `ps_tabs_capacity`.

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat, I understand your point. I tried only with:                                                                        path('sins/ps_tabs/', views.index, name='ps_tabs2'),     and  in function index I put

    
    return render(request,'app_sins/ps_tabs_capacity.html', {"all_post" : r1,"jokso" : r2}), but still does not work. It seems some very small mistake or order of commands..

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat , I managed to work. I noticed in cmd log that when I click on tab it was searching for /sins/ , so I add in url.py path for sins/ , and total url.py is now  path('sins/ps_tabs/', views.index, name='ps_tabs2'),
         path('sins/', views.index, name='ps_tabs1'),  But I have no idea why when tab is clicked is searching for /sins/ ?? It will request on all others clicked tabs the same path /sins/. Any comment here?  Thanks anyhow!